# If Entity does not have properties for all the attributes for database View, will it break the application?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first, odp.net

I am generating entities from Database for Code First Model.
While adding "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" in Visual Studio, I selected "Code From Database" and selected database View in Entity Data Model Wizard. Then Visual Studio generated correct entity for the view:

```
[Table("schemaName.emp_v")]
public partial class Employee
{
```

This view is common and owned by other team and new columns can be added later. To simulate this situation, I commented a few properties in Employee entity generated  for `schemaName.emp_v` view. I was expecting EF exception as number of entity properties and number of view attributes are not matching; and application worked same way as before commenting the entity properties.

When new columns are added in the view after code is generated, would it break my application as my application does have corresponding properties for those newly added columns (If Entity does not have properties for all the attributes for database View, will it break the application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When new columns are added in the view after code is generated, would it break my application as my application does have corresponding properties for those newly added columns

Not for selects.

For updates and inserts it depends. If some of the new columns are required (`not null`) then you will not be able to give them a value, and thus add and update operations will fail.

Remember, in the end EF just generates SQL. If it has sufficient information to create SQL that executes without error then it will work.